# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

3D Printing's [First Pro-Tem moderator election](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators is:

[image: MOD1_NAME]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://3Dprinting.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking tbm0115 who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5831275661230080).

Comment: Thanks @tbm0115 :-)

Answer (score 5):

Congrats 0scar! Nicely done :o)

Comment: Yeah, well done @0scar and also everyone who participated :-)

Comment: Thanks, and thank you all for your support!

Comment: Congrats 0scar. Enjoy your new found executive power!

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to all the candidates - I think you all do a great job to improve the site in your own ways.

Answer (score 5):

A big thank you to @tbm0115 who has volunteered modding the site for this long period!

Comment: Thank you. I unfortunately have become swamped in my personal life and haven't been able to keep up with the duties. But, I leave moderation here in good hands with you, Greenonline, and StarWind0. Thanks to all three of you for the work you already have done and will continue to do.